# Is there a python way for reducing the training time of convolution neural network?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm building a keras model of convolution neural network for predicting the correct class and classify the tested objects. the model have the conv2D, activation, maxpooling, dropout, flatten, dense layers. after that I training the network on large dataset, but it take a very long time for training, it may reach to 3,4 days, What I need is to reduce the time required to training the network, Is there any way to do that in python?

I have tried to optimize the learning rate by using the LR_Finder class as follow:

```
from LR_Finder import LRFinder
lr_finder = LRFinder(min_lr=1e-5,max_lr=1e-2, steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(len(trainX) // BS), epochs=100)
```

But this also did not give me any reduction about the time required.

This is the code of my model:

```
class SmallerVGGNet:
@staticmethod
def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
    # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1

    # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
    # and channels dimension
    if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
        inputShape = (depth, height, width)
        chanDim = 1

    # CONV => RELU => POOL
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
        input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    # softmax classifier
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    # return the constructed network architecture
    return model
```

and after that I trained the model as following code:

```
EPOCHS = 100
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
IMAGE_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)

data = []
labels = []

# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images("Dataset")))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)
# loop over the input images
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)

# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
print("[INFO] data matrix: {:.2f}MB".format(data.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))

# binarize the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
                                 labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
               height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
                     horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize the model
model = SmallerVGGNet.build(width=IMAGE_DIMS[1], height=IMAGE_DIMS[0],
                        depth=IMAGE_DIMS[2], classes=len(lb.classes_))
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= opt,
          metrics=["accuracy"])
print("model compiled in few minutes successfully ^_^")

# train the network
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

According to this code,I expected the output required some minutes or may be a few hours, but when it reach to training in `model.fit_generator` step, the actual time required is about many hours for every epoch and it requires some days to train all the network or it may be crash and stop working. Is there any way to reduce the training time?

Comment: Keras is available in [PyPy](https://pypy.org/). You could try that to speed things up. Another approach is optimizing you backend (for example by [running TensorFlow on GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu)).

Comment: @agtoever thank you for your reply, my device without GPU, I'm using CPU only, do you have another way to speed up training process?

Answer (score 0):

set **use_multiprocessing=True** and **workers>1** when you call fit_generator because the default is to execute the generator on the main thread only

Comment: The default value of works is actually 1 and the generator will be executed on main thread when `works == 0`. [more](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator)

Comment: @Jenia thank you for your answer, I tried what you mentioned, but did not speed up the process and also the use_multiprocessing=True  caused crash and stoping the training process, do you have another way?